# Android- How to restrict users to be active in more than one device?

Tags: android, session, authentication, push-notification

I am developing an Android application in which I would like to restrict an user to access only one device at a time.

Lets say, User A is logging in first time using the Android application and from next time,the app logs in automatically using the credentials stored in the local storage.

If the same user is logging in with the web application with the same credentials and changed the password, the mobile application should force the user to login as soon as the password is changed.Even if the mobile application is being active and doing some tasks , it has to be cancelled and force user to login once again.

My idea was to use Push Notification in Mobile app to terminate the session as soon as the user has logged in/changed the password from web application. But the bottle neck is that there is an option in device settings to block the notification.

Please help me to find a way to overcome this.

Comment: Always verify on the server. This is not an android issue.

Comment: Since you login the user automatically, I assume you have some sort of access token provide at log in/register. This access token can be invalidated on the server when certain operations occur (i.e change password). If the token is invalidated all mobile request should fail with a specific error code (401 - Unauthorised). When the app detects this error, it should redirect the user to the login.

Comment: @danypata I do  not use the token. We use liferay sdk. it provides the API to check if the user is already logged in . Based on that , I navigate to LoginActivity/HomeScreen

Comment: There is no option to stop Push Notification in Android but there is an option to stop Notification from being shown.

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** option in devices to block Push Notifications. But there is an option to stop an App from showing Notifications in the Device Notification Bar and also there is another option to stop an App from using Data (Internet) in the background (when not in use!). This is a different case with your issue.

Here is how! On your server send message to a user Device using `Firebase`. You should send Data Messages so as to gain full control and because you do not need to show any notification to a user device. When that message reaches to the user. You should Logout the user. Remember all this happens in the background the user does not notice anything or any notification shown.You can learn more about [message types here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

Comment: Thanks . Let me try using push notification and check if the code snippet for clearing the data is triggered